# Raise one div over another one

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have two html `div`'s.

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;background-color:red;" id="1">
<div style="height:200px;width:200px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;background-color:yellow;" id="2">
</div>
</div>
```

These two `div` are positioned on the same place. So, the second `div` is raised over the first `div`. I want to raise first `div` over the second one.

I can do it by changing the position of the two `div` one to other like this:

```
    <div style="height:200px;width:200px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;background-color:yellow;" id="1">

<div style="height:100px;width:100px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;background-color:red;" id="2">
    </div>
    </div>
```

But I can't do it. Because I want to make #2 sibling of #1.
How to do it without changing the position of #1 and #2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the yellow one to be as a child of the red, in that case there is no way to bring the red (parent) to be in front of the child.

What i've done is to make both of the divs to be a siblings. In that way you can control the `z-index` property to bring one of them to the front.

```html
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;background-color:red; z-index:10;" id="1"></div>
<div style="height:200px;width:200px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;background-color:yellow;z-index:0;" id="2">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot.